# C - atmega328p - I don't understand what is wrong

Tags: c, embedded, atmega

i do not unterstand why my code isnt working(doISR). What its supposed to do:

-there is a running light(6 LEDs) and 3 Buttons. I need to press the button at the right time(Button 1, if LED 1 or 2 is on....etc). if its correct: increase the speed, if not: reset.

i bet its a blunder, but i dont get it :)

```
   void wait(void) {
   while (!(TIFR1 & (1 << OCF1A))) // wait
   ;
   TIFR1 |= (1 << OCF1A); // delete Interrupt flag 
}

volatile bool ISRhasHappend = false;

ISR(PCINT0_vect) {
    ISRhasHappend = true;
}

int main(void) {
    OCR1A = 3125 - 1; //2 seconds
    TCCR1B |= (1 << WGM12); //turn on CTC mode
    TCCR1B |= (1 << CS12) | (1 << CS10); //Prescalemode 101 -> 1024 Takt
    DDRB = (1 << PCINT5); 
    DDRC = 0x3f; 
    PCICR = 0x3f; //Pin Change Interrupt Control Register
    PCMSK0 = (1 << PCINT0) | (1 << PCINT2) | (1 << PCINT4); 

   sei();
   doRunningLight();
   if (ISRhasHappend == true) {
        doISR();
   }
}

void doISR() {

    //while timee >0
    for(int x=3125;x>0;x=x-250){
        //if LEDs 0+1 on, and button0 pressed ...etc                                            
        if ((PORTC & (0b00000011)) && (PINB & (1 << PINB0)) || (PORTC & 
        (0b00001100)) && (PINB & (1 << PINB2)) || (PORTC & (0b00110000)) && 
      (PINB & (1 << PINB4))) {
               //All led lights up
               PORTC |= 0x3f;
               wait();
               //reduce timer if catched the light
               OCR1A = x;
           }
           else {
               //turn signal
               for (int y = 1; y < 5; y++) {
                   PORTB ^= (1 << PCINT5);
                   wait();
               }
                //back to 3124 if failed
                OCR1A = 3125 - 1;
           }
    }
    ISRhasHappend = false;
}

void doRunningLight(){

   while(1) {
       for (int i = 0; i<6; i++){
           PORTC |= (1<<i);
           wait();
           PORTC  &= ~(1<<i);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Step through the code with the debugger and a problem will become obvious.  What happens when you try to step over the call to `doRunningLight()`?

Comment: Provide more information on what is going wrong, when and in which way. For those not familiar with exactly your environment, please describe the mechanisms around your code, i.e. how/when the ISR is executed. In my experience, getting the ISR executed at the time you expect is a challenge. Can you demonstrate that that part is working as expected?

Comment: @Yunnosch it does not executed the ISR part. Only the Running Light is working. When i put doISR in the Interrupt its working a little(only a little becuse of the wait() in the interrupt. therfore i need the method and  ISRhasHappend)

Comment: If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/  
The most useful hint in there for your case is probably rubberducking. I.e. find somebody extremely patient (but does not really need to understand programming), then explain every line single line of your code, in excrutiating detail. Quote from the manual, lecture on ISR mechanisms. Impress her/him with your knowledge and understanding. The point is that at some time in your talking you are almost guaranteed to go " ... and then - hmmmm - maybe - ...". That's when you found.

Comment: Feel free to edit your question for rubberducking. I offer being your rubber duck.

Comment: duck, the code order is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The function `doRunningLight()` never returns, so the code that you wrote after it to check `ISRhasHappend` and call `doIsr` will never run.  You will need to think of a different way to handle your events, probably without using blocking delay loops.

I would also question whether you actually need a pin-change interrupt.  Button presses are slow enough that your microcontroller should be able to detect them by reading the pin in the main loop.